# Parsing JSON response in c#

Tags: c#, json, api, post, byte

If it helps, I'm using the CampBX API to get funds in my account. I wrote the following code to make the API Call:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            String url = "https://CampBX.com/api/myfunds.php";

            var data = new NameValueCollection();
            data["user"] = "USERNAME";
            data["pass"] = "PASSWORD";
            var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
        }
```

`WebClient.UploadValues()` returns a `byte[]` and I have no idea how to correctly parse that.

[Here is the CampBX info, under Account Balances](https://campbx.com/api.php#account).

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you need to use a JSON parser.  Personally I like [Newtonsoft.Json](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) and it is what I will use in this example.

The first step is converting the `byte[]` to a sequence of characters, either a string object or a `TextReader`.  The second step is to pass this information to the parser.  So, in your case, the code would look something like this:

```
JToken parsedToken;
using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(response))) {
    parsedToken = JToken.ReadFrom(responseReader);
}
```

The `parsedToken` object can then be used to extract whatever data you need.  (See [the documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) for information on extracting data from a `JToken` object.)

Note that `WebClient.UploadValues()` discards the information regarding the response entity's character encoding.  `StreamReader` will use UTF-8 encoding by default, which is sufficient to parse UTF-8 or ASCII.  Depending on the JSON encoder used by the server, the response may always be ASCII-compatible, so you might not have to worry about it.  Nevertheless, it's something you should investigate.

Answer (score 0):

DataContractJsonSerializer built-in object will be your friend here, provided you know what is the internal structure of the returned object (or can at least guess it, from the JSON).

The steps are:
Define a contract class to hold the deserialized JSON object

```
namespace AppNameSpace  
{
    [DataContract]              /* Place this inside your app namespace */
    internal class iResponse    /*Name this class appropriately */
    {
        [DataMember]
        internal string field1;
        [DataMember]
        internal string field2;
        [DataMember]
        internal Int32 field3;
    }
    ...
}
```

The actual parsing itself is about three lines

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(iOpenParams));
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream(response);
iResponse resp_json = (iResponse)ser.ReadObject(stream1);
```

For more details and examples, refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simpler:

```
Object retorno;
var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(response))) 
{
    retorno = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(responseReader.ReadToEnd());
}
```